# How do Promises/A+ implementations vary?

Tags: javascript, promise, q, bluebird, rsvp-promise

What aspects of a promise library does the spec **not** cover? What kind of things vary between implementations?

Please illustrate with examples of actual differences (eg between Bluebird and Q).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Almost everything. The Promises/A+ spec is aimed for promise interoperability, it's built so promise libraries (and now, native promises) can *talk to each other*. The idea is for it to be possible to predict how a promise behaves and to define how promises are *assimilated* by other libraries.

Quoting the specification:

> This specification details the behavior of the `then` method, providing an interoperable base which all Promises/A+ conformant promise implementations can be depended on to provide. As such, the specification should be considered very stable. Although the Promises/A+ organization may occasionally revise this specification with minor backward-compatible changes to address newly-discovered corner cases, we will integrate large or backward-incompatible only after careful consideration, discussion, and testing. Finally, **the core Promises/A+ specification does not deal with how to create, fulfill, or reject promises, choosing instead to focus on providing an interoperable then method**. Future work in companion specifications may touch on these subjects.

The following are not covered:

- Creating a promise (that's the [promise constructor](https://github.com/promises-aplus/constructor-spec) spec).
- Promise aggregation (although most implementations support `.all`).
- Progression (that's the [progression spec](https://github.com/promises-aplus/progress-spec), which will soon be replaced imo).
- Cancellation (that's the [cancellation spec](https://github.com/promises-aplus/cancellation-spec)).
- Unhandled rejection monitoring (there is no spec, but there is an inspection discussion).
- Stack traces.

Bluebird and Q for example, are both completely Promises/A+ complaint but differ on a lot of these:

- The next Q, v2 introduces estimation, where Bluebird intends to deprecate progression eventually in favor of something like C#'s IProgress.
- Creating a promise is usually done with deferreds in Q (although it now offers a promise constructor variant), Bluebird encourages the promise constructor.
- Bluebird has more robust and stronger promisification abilities, turning a whole callback API to promises in a single command. Q author Kris built Q-IO which manually promisifies the filesystem and http modules.
- Bluebird allows scoped binding of `this` value via `.bind`, and promise array methods (`.map`,`.reduce`,`.filter` etc).
- Q has primitives like asynchronous queues, and RPC via Q-connection in mind,
- Bluebird is about 100 times faster, has better stack traces, and automatic unhandled rejection detection. It also consumes a lot less RAM memory per promise.

[Here is another reference](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/issues/63#issuecomment-34140791)