# jQuery deferred promise

Tags: jquery, promise

I have this code below which is not working as I am expecting.Here GetAllFileNames is Async function and I want to do some sequential action based on result of this funciton. So I am using Jquery promise. But I feel that statement return `deferred.resolve(GetAllFileNames)` is not correct.It immediately calls `promise.then` without even waiting for GatAllFileNames to finish.Please note this is not actually working code.

```
function getfilenames() {
  var deferred = $.Deferred();

  if(condition == true) {
    return deferred.resolve(JSON.parse(allFileNames));
  } else {
    return deferred.resolve(GetAllFileNames());
  }
}    

var promise = getfilenames();      
promise.then(function(fileNames) {
  result.fileNames = fileNames; 
});
```

UPDATE: I tried some of your comments ,but none of them is working.Here is one of example which is not working

```
<!DOCTYPE html> <html> <head> <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script> <script> $(function () {
    var deferred = $.Deferred();
    var result = {};
    var GetAllFileNames = function () {
        return {
            "allFileNames": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
        };
    };

    function getfilenames(condition) {

        if (condition == true) {
            return deferred.notify(JSON.parse(allFileNames));
        } else {
            return deferred.notify(GetAllFileNames());
        }
    };

    deferred.then(
    // `deferred.done`
    function (fileNames) {
        result.fileNames = fileNames;
        $("<span>" + result.fileNames.allFileNames + "</span>")
            .appendTo("body");          console.log(JSON.stringify(fileNames));
    }
    // `deferred.fail`
    ,


    function () {
        console.log(new Error("getfilenames error").message);
    } );

    getfilenames(false);

}) </script> </head> <body>

</body> </html>
```

Comment: What is method of confirming `GetAllFileNames()` is complete ? Is there `length` property of items to query ? If tasks to perform after `GetAllFileNames()` ,  could utilize `deferred.notify` to provide notification of `GetAllFileNames()` with `deferred.progress` , then `resolve` `deferred` within `progress` when complete ; which would then call `deferred.then`

Comment: Just do `function getfilenames() { return condition ? $.when(JSON.parse(allFileNames)) : GetAllFileNames(); }` why all that cruft? Why a deferred? Why a resolve? This is a very messy way to do something simple.

Comment: @Alien01 Not certain about logic at `if` statement ? , what `condition` is ? , or what expected return value of `getallfilenames` ?

Composed with `condition` being `false` ; not certain about `getallfilenames` possible return value(s) ; what `allFileNames` is , if return by function within `getallfilenames` ? See post

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Nice ! See also `$.when(condition ? getfilenames() : GetAllFileNames())`

Comment: @guest271314 that's even nicer (and closer to what I usually do) :) You should edit your answer to get rid of that [deferred anti pattern](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-deferred-anti-pattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it)

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Interesting reads . Still reviewing . Actually was not going to include `this.resolve()` portion ; for two point 1) not certain about what the exact item to resolve was _expected_ to be ; 2) in this instance , it was the `progress` notifications that appear to be primary goal of task ; or "when x tasks complete , do stuff" ? Is utilizing notify-progress pattern considered an "anti-pattern" ? even if utilizing `deferred` object for the re-usable notify-progress functionality - not to resolve a deferred object , or return a deferred.promise ? Alternatives? Thanks for the light

Comment: @guest271314 progression is a completely broken API that does not compose well, it was deprecated in Q and will not move to V2, it was deprecated in Bluebird and it will not ever make it into ES6 promises - for more information about it see https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#progression-migration - Domenic and KrisKowal have also written about it. If you need to emit multiple events from a promise rather than just completing or failing you should use an event emitter.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum jquery's version of notify-progress considered broken / perhaps removed from next versions ? Similar was mentioned http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24971676/notify-after-async-task-is-done/, see Answers, comments  . Several options for `deferred` or `promises` appear to be available for utilization ? Selection of which to employ depend on composer / adjuster of composition / task to perform ? Could also compose / re-compose deferred/promises/progress , see http://stackoverflow.com/a/23587868/2801559 , http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/N6EgU ; What would edit post to ?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I tried to use function getfilenames() { return condition ? $.when(JSON.parse(allFileNames)) : GetAllFileNames(); }, but how can I use .then ,when condition is true. Since it returns a JSON object and not a funtion , so .then wont work in that case.

Answer (score 0):

You should resolve the deffered when operation is acutully performed.

In this [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/ostzdgpv/6/) 'Got all files' will be displayed before 'get all files'

> Got all file names
>   Get all files names

```
function GetAllFileNames(ms) {
    //simulate delay
    setTimeout( function() { console.log('Get all files names') ; return 20;}, ms);
} 

function getfilenames() {

    var def = $.Deferred();

    def.resolve(GetAllFileNames(2000));

    return def;
}

getfilenames().then( function() { console.log('Got all file names'); });
```

but [here](http://jsfiddle.net/7ec1h9yg/2/) console log order would be

> Get all file names
>   Got all file names

```
function GetAllFileNames(ms, def) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log('Get all file names');
        def.resolve();
        return 20;
    }, ms);
}

function getfilenames() {

    var def = $.Deferred();

    var result = GetAllFileNames(2000, def);

    return def;
}

getfilenames().then(function() {
    console.log('Got all file names');
});
```

because deffered is resolved when GotAllFilesNames is ready.

Comment: You shouldn't ever write a function that takes a deferred to fulfill - just merge them into one. It also would make the difference more clear, it's a bit difficult to spot here.

Comment: @Bergi, Thanks for note. I thought it's easy to demonstrate that way but could you please explain, why it's shouldn't be done? I'll adjust the demo.

Comment: It can be helpful in some rare settings, but in general you're just spreading one functionality over two functions. `getfilenames` doesn't really do very much, creating the promise should be part of the function that actually does the async call.

Comment: Thanks again but I thought there was a big drawback you were pointing out with 'shouldn't ever' statement. Anyways it was for example to demonstrate & not actual getallfilenames implementation. About resolving deffered, that's what I exactly said in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Edit, updated ; see comments at Question

Try (this pattern)

```
 var result = {};
 var GetAllFileNames = function () {
        return {
            "allFileNames": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
        };
    };
var getfilenames = function (condition) { // `condition` ?
    return $.when(
             condition 
             ? JSON.parse(allFileNames)
             : GetAllFileNames()
           ); 
    };

    getfilenames(false) // `condition` ?
    .then( 
    // `done`
      function (fileNames) {
        result.fileNames = fileNames;
        $("<span>" + result.fileNames.allFileNames + "</span>")
            .appendTo("body");
    }
    // `fail`
    , function () {
        console.log(new Error("getfilenames error").message);
    });
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/9f12san7/

Comment: Why do you (try to) use a progress notification to resolve the deferred?

Comment: Questions asking for clarifications should go in comments on the original post, not in an answer.

Comment: @Bergi Found pattern of utilizing `deferred.notify` and `deferred.progress` for "polling" , or intermediate tasks , practical. Those methods appear rarely utilized at SO Questions . Just a pattern ; progress could be run several times without actually resolving the deferred . If arguments provided to notify-progress meet condition , resolve deferred , there . Issue with utilizing progress callback to notify progress "events" ? , before actually resolving or rejecting a deferred ? Does pattern possess potential issue ? If possible , can illuminate on reason noted pattern ?

Comment: @Bergi Updated. Tried to include detail / description of how arrived at Answer within initial post . Thanks

Comment: This is not working when getfilenamesis called with true condition,getfilenames(true)

Comment: @Alien01 The piece at post composed to _only_ return `false` ; a template , or pattern , to possibly include other pieces or values not included at OP . Not certain about what `condition` is ? Do both `getfilenames` and `GetAllFileNames` return same result ? If possible , could provide descriptions of `condition` , and expected return values of `getfilenames` and `GetAllFileNames` ? Thanks

Comment: Could re-arrange piece to call async function first . If load time excessive , or other "condition", `reject` deferred, which would call `fail` , where non-async `getfilenames` called ?

Comment: Yes, there is an issue with using progress callbacks to resolve a deferred - the progress events are thought to notify *subscribers* of your promise, not to notify yourself. The callbacks should not change the state of your deferred - and usually they only have access to the promise (which they can't resolve) anyway. If you want to use something like this, you at least need to create a *new* promise which represent something like "the first progress event that meets <condition>, or the result of the other promise".

Comment: @Alien01 If possible , could describe `condition` ? What adjusts `condition` between `true` or `false` ? Is order 1) call `getfilenames` ? which returns ? 2) if `getfilenames` _does not_ return `condition` (`true`) , e.g., `json` object, `GetAllFileNames` is called ? Or , is order reverse of above ? 1) Call `GetAllFileNames` ; if return result `true` (`json`) object ; 2) call `getfilenames` to further process `json` object ? Necessity of redundancy between `getfilenames` and `GetAllFileNames` ? if they return same object ? Thanks

Comment: @Bergi Interesting concepts. Not appear to be an actual _drawback_ to utilizing `deferred.notify` to resolve a `deferred` (< v1.8) ; if the publisher of the notification _permits_ the subscriber to achieve this ? There seem a similar pattern of concepts relating to deferred/promises - particularly jquery's model. Though , the object(s) could be malleable enough to support different concepts; experimentation of the breadth of possibilities ? `notify/progress` _could_ be versatile enough for varying usages ; though could use `$.queue` or `$.Callbacks` for notify; used already internally ? Thanks